# Can I custom draw Jface TableColumn headers?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, custom-draw

I'm programming a JFace Table with owner-drawing by assigning the columns an OwnerDrawCellLabelProvider. I'm now happy with how the body of the table looks, but would like to also adjust the look of the table header.

Is there any API way I can get access to how the header of each column is drawn? I can always create a second custom-drawn table to serve as the header of the first table, but that seems a little silly.

Comment: There has been a enhancement request for this [242419](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=242419) open for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Nebula `Grid` widget. It has a `GridTableViewer` as well as a `GridTreeViewer`. Pretty handy. It allows customisation on column as well as row headers. See snippets [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.nebula.snippets/src/org/eclipse/nebula/snippets/grid)